# Prevent activities (event, task, and email) in Opportunity and child objects from appearing in Account too

Tags: opportunity, account, activities

I am trying to prevent activities from an Opportunity and child objects from rolling up to a related Account's activity component:

Here is the Account activity component. Tasks from related opportunities are rolling up. I would like to prevent this from happening.

[image]

Are there any settings to disable this? I have been doing some research but not come across anything.